# Вставка значений из БД в документ Word с учетом словоформ.

Tags: c#, ms-word

Мне необходимо написать приложение, которое будет открывать шаблон Word'a и вставлять в него в определенных местах значения из БД. Я собираюсь для достижения этих целей использовать OpenXML. Нет никаких проблем, чтобы брать некую метку, допустим [#ParamName#] и заменять ее по четкому совпадению.

http://www.dotnet-geek.co.uk/index.php/openxml-word-templates-processing/
В этой статье описано, как заменять метки, но если мы точно знаем ее формат.

В базе данных я собираюсь хранить пары значений [#ParamName#] и  Value.

Но в моем приложении подразумевается, что одно и тоже значение может использоваться в разных падежах и числах. Хотелось бы в шаблоне писать что-то типа [#ParamName родп, едч#] или [#ParamName датп, мнч#] (ну или как-то еще указывать параметры словоформы). И вот необходимо найти значение для ParamName и поставить его в нужную форму. И как склонять существительные программно, это я знаю. Вопрос заключается в том, как парсить шаблон, или как еще можно достичь поставленной цели.